# How to use container neighbours in std algorithms in a right way

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11

Are std algorithms designed to use several neighbor elements in container?

Here what I have done to read samples from file(each sample has it's own offset)

```
long offsets[] = { 0x00000000, 0x00000010, 0x00000020, .... }

ifstream file(path, ios::binary);
vector<sample> samples;
for_each(begin(offsets), end(offsets), [](long &offset){
    auto sampleSize = *(&offset+1)-offset;
    sample s;
    file.read( s.GetBuffer(), sampleSize);
    samples.push_back(s);
});
```

To figure out size I need two adjacent elements from vector. I also think I could use std::advance() or std::next() instead of *(&offset+1).
Is it the right approach at all here to use standard algorithm? If yes, which algorithms are designed to be used in this way?

Comment: `*(&offset+1)` has undefined behavior when `offset` refers to the last element in `offsets`.

Comment: If you have C++11 support, why not use a [range-based for loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) instead of `for_each` with a lambda? Though in your case it wont work either. Instead I would suggest a normal `for` loop with a counter. You don't *have* to use algorithms all the time you know. :)

Comment: Take two (lazy) skip range adaptors and zip them. Of course writing them for the above code is massive over engineering, but `boost` probably has them already.

Comment: You can almost use http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/adjacent_difference but you need to deal with the fact that it insists on copying the first element of the range. Sometimes that's ok, though.

Comment: Well, at first I've tried range-for loop and for_each, they do the job(if I checked for the last element :) ) and then general question raised if I could use std algos for things like image filtering that require to examine several neighboring pixel values.

Answer (score 1):

With boost zip iterator, you may do something like:

```
// assume that offsets is not empty.
std::for_each(
    boost::make_zip_iterator(boost::make_tuple(begin(offsets), begin(offsets + 1))),
    boost::make_zip_iterator(boost::make_tuple(end(offsets) - 1, end(offsets))),
    [&](const boost::tuple<const long&, const long&>& t) {
        auto sampleSize = t.get<1>() - t.get<0>();
        sample s;
        file.read(s.GetBuffer(), sampleSize);
        samples.push_back(s);
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly a job for [std::adjacent_difference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/adjacent_difference), e.g.

```
long offsets[] = { 0x00000000, 0x00000010, 0x00000020, 0x00000030 };

std::vector<long> diff(end(offsets) - begin(offsets));
std::adjacent_difference(begin(offsets), end(offsets), diff.begin());

ifstream file(path, ios::binary);
vector<sample> samples;

for_each(diff.begin() + 1, diff.end(), [&](long size){
    sample s;
    file.read(s.GetBuffer(), size);
    samples.push_back(s);
});
```

or, if you don't need `offsets` again, you can just overwrite it:

```
long offsets[] = { 0x00000000, 0x00000010, 0x00000020, 0x00000030 };
std::adjacent_difference(begin(offsets), end(offsets), begin(offsets));

ifstream file(path, ios::binary);
vector<sample> samples;

for_each(begin(offsets) + 1, end(offsets), [&](long size){
    sample s;
    file.read(s.GetBuffer(), size);
    samples.push_back(s);
});
```

`+ 1` is needed because the first element of the output sequence of `std::adjacent_difference` equals the first element of the input; so you need to skip it.